# Reintegrating a Branch in Subclipse

Tags: svn, merge, subclipse, svn-reintegrate

My issue is basically the same as the following question, except I am using subclipse with svn 1.6.17, which was never really answered.

[Missing ranges error message when reintegrating a branch into trunk in Subversion 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472249/problem-reintegrating-a-branch-into-the-trunk-in-subversion-1-5)

I have merged all my changes into branch which seemed to work fine. However when I try and reintegrate the branch back into the trunk I get the following error:

> Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 16530 through 24993 were
>   previously merged from Trunk-Repo-URL to the reintegrate source, but
>   this is not the case.

And then it lists some of the files with missing ranges.

When I go to the branch and view the history of those files they are all at revision 24992(I believe they all had issues to correct when been merged). The trunk logically has older revisions.

Any pointers to where I am going wrong as the error seems to be telling me to do something that I have already done.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes out of Subversion itself.  It means those files have subtree mergeinfo that indicates they have not had all changes merged into them.  The way to resolve the issue should be to merge all revisions from trunk to the root of the project.  This should cleanup the subtree mergeinfo to indicate that those files have all revisions merged to them.

The revision number on the file in history is meaningless in this case.  The message is related to the svn:mergeinfo on the subtrees that were listed in the error.  Again, doing a complete merge to their parent and committing the result, should clean that up.

Comment: 'The way to resolve the issue should be to merge all revisions from trunk to the root of the project.'- How do I go about this? When I try and merge 'All revisions' from trunk to the branch it completes without merging anything and when I ask to specify ranges it tells me that there is nothing to merge. Your reply has led me to this http://blog.syntevo.net/2011/03/16/1300268640000.html which might solve my problem, or more likely just case further ones!